# Prevent NavigationLink popping back when the list item is removed from the list

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the follwing SwiftUI view and `devices` is a state continuously getting updated from parent view. If I navigate to `DetailView` by one of the link and the corresponding `device` is removed from `devices` while I am viewing its `DetailView`, the navigation pops back. How do I prevent it from popping back even when `device` is removed from `devices`?

```swift
class Datasource : ObservableObject{
    @Published public var devices : [devices]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var datasource = Datasource()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            DeviceList(devices: datasource.devices)
                .padding()
                .navigationTitle("Demo")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}

struct DeviceList: View{
    var devices: [Device]
    var body: some View{
        if(devices.isEmpty)
        {
            Text("Scanning...")
        }
        else
        {
            ScrollView{
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(devices) { device in
                        NavigationLink{
                            DetailView(device: Device)
                        } label: {
                            DeviceItem(device: Device)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.plain)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

I've found [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665369) which mentioned a solution to pause the update of `ObservableObject`, which seems solving my problem but I don't want to modify my datasource to `PausableObservableObject`. Instead I would like to create a generic class `class Pausable<T> : PausableObservableObject` to encapsulate my datasource, but I don't know the correct way to do it. Here is my attempt which is not successfully.

```swift
class Pausable<T> : PausableObservableObject{
    @Published var value: T
    
    private var sink: AnyCancellable?
    
    init(initialValue:T, publisher: Published<T>.Publisher) {
        self.value = initialValue
        super.init()
        self.$value = publisher
        sink = publisher.sink {
            self.value = $0
            self.publishWillUpdate()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `ObservableObject` relevant here? You are not using observable objects here are you?

Comment: @Sweeper updated my post to show the parent view and data source.

Comment: I see. Can you try using a `NavigationStack` instead?

Comment: I tried `NavigationStack`, it does prevent popping, but it display nothing after `device` is removed form `devices` since it find nothing to display in `navigationDestination`. But this inspired me to my workaround. Since I have another `allDevices` array keeping track of all devices (including those removed from `devices`), I can simply do `ForEach(allDevices)`, then display `EmptyView()` as the label for the `NavigationLink` if `devices` does not contain that `device`.